# SSRS report does not work remotly

Tags: reporting-services

I have one problem with creating dynamically data source SSRS reports.
Locally in SSDT tool is working fine, but after publishing, on Report Manager, gives mi silly error : "An error has occurred during report processing. Could not find stored procedure XXX". The stored procedure is created in the same way in all databases.
What is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is only with this one `stored proc` then try using the full name including Schema.
e.g.

```
dbo.spr_YourStoredProc
```

Or feel free to share the image of `stored proc` name in `database explorer window` and your `data source window` so that we can comment better?

Answer (score -1):

I use dynamically data source in order to get the same report in different companies.Firstly, I created parameter @company that contains values of Initial Catalog (database of each company). In data source I created expression:
="Data Source=10.0.23.8;Initial Catalog="+Parameters!company.Value.Then I embedded
this data source in Data Set. Note: This Data Set gave result, while connection string was static(one company). Locally in SSDT it works, when I change Data Source that has expression instead of static connection string, but in Report Manager is not working. Locally I used Windows integrated authentication. Stored procedure is created in all databases.Remotly I get this message: An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DnevnaProdajaRC102'(rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.neo_dnevna_102_novo'.
If data set is simply query, then I get message: An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'SpisakRadnika'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Invalid object name 'Radnik'. Radnik is a table and is located in all company databases.